# Tkinter freezes while waiting for callback using after

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to build a small **Python GUI app with Tkinter**. A main window opens when the app is opened. Then one can click on a button to open a new toplevel. In this toplevel, there is a timer (countdown) that starts when a button is pressed.

My problem is that the toplevel freezes while the timer counts down. I have probably missed something fundamental about how Tkinter works (and how to structure the code). I am hoping you may clarify why the code is not working as intended.

```
from tkinter import *

class Application:def __init__(self, master=NONE):
    self.root = Tk()

    btnTimer = Button(self.root, text="Open timer", command=self.open_timer)
    btnTimer.grid(row=1, column=0)

    self.root.mainloop()

def open_timer(self):
    # Hide main window
    self.root.withdraw()  # Hide main window

    # Make window for controls
    self.wdowControl = Toplevel(self.root)

    # Timer
    self.wdowControl.timerText = Label(self.wdowControl, text="00:00:00", font=("Helvetica", 80))
    self.wdowControl.timerText.grid(row=0, column=0)

    btnStart = Button(self.wdowControl, text="Start timer", command=self.start_timer)
    btnStart.grid(row=1, column=0)

def start_timer(self):
    self.update_timer(5) # Timer in seconds

def update_timer(self, t):
    if t > 0:
        m, s = divmod(t, 60)
        h, m = divmod(m, 60)

        timeLeft = "%d:%02d:%02d" % (h, m, s)
        self.wdowControl.timerText.configure(text=timeLeft)
        t -= 1
        self.wdowControl.after(1000, self.update_timer(t)) 
    else:
        self.wdowControl.timerText.configure(text="00:00:00", fg='red')

app = Application())
```

**Note:** *I started coding with Python yesterday and I've probably not started with the basic stuff I should learn first. But hey, this is what makes me happy. :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use after in the following line;

```
self.wdowControl.after(1000, self.update_timer(t))
```

The function is being called straight away. This means that your program freezes up, as it just calls itself again and again.

To pass variables as you are doing in this case using `after`, you specify it by using another comma after the function name. Thus, to fix your program, you need to change the line I mentioned to this:

```
self.wdowControl.after(1000, self.update_timer, t)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks! Do you know the logic behind this?

Comment: When you put  `()` after a phrase, Python will try to call that function, regardless of whether it is within a statement such as `after`, in this case. Tkinter therefore takes the function name you wish to call, and any arguments you wish to pass it, so that it can do so when you specified.